# how to use node.js in multi-device-hybrid-application

Tags: android, node.js, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I 'm novice to multi-device-hybrid app template ,I want to use node.js in it. How to add Node.js references and all other stuffs to develop multi-device-hybrid application especially targeting Android?

Comment: Yes, you can develop apps using Node.js for Android. What kind of app are you trying to develop using node.js?

Comment: @ Abhishek - Howdy.. node.js only for Webscraping Purpose.Is there any good alternative to that ?